# ¿En Javascript cómo puedo hacer que los productos se ordenen de menor a mayor, si al hacerlo, un elemento siempre se coloca por encima del orden?

Tags: javascript

No logro hacer que los productos se ordenen de menor a mayor pues el producto "Auto" siempre se coloca por encima del ordenamiento y no entiendo por qué... utilicé el método `.sort` e incluso un `for`, tal como se ve casi al final del código, pero no encuentro la  manera de realizarlo.

```js
class Productos {
  constructor(idProducto, nombreProducto, precio) {
    this.idProducto = idProducto;
    this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
    this.precio = precio;

  }
  sumarIva() {
    this.precio = this.precio * 1.21;
    return this.precio;
    //función creada para agregar el Impuesto al Valor Agregado al precio de los productos.
  }
  descuentoParaUsuarios() {
    this.precio = this.precio - 2000;
    return this.precio;
    //función para realizar descuentos a los usuarios registrados (Más adelante el programa podrá distinguir entre Usuarios registrados y no registrados).
  }
}

//Objetos con los datos de los productos.
const producto0 = new Productos(0, "Ovni", 5000);
const producto1 = new Productos(1, "Tren", 8000);
const producto2 = new Productos(2, "Auto", 30000);
const producto3 = new Productos(3, "Moto", 4000);


//Estructura producto 0.
let precioOriginalProducto0 = producto0.precio;
let producto0PrecioConIva = producto0.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto0);
let producto0ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto0.descuentoParaUsuarios();


//Estructura producto 1.
let precioOriginalProducto1 = producto1.precio;
let producto1PrecioConIva = producto1.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto1);
let producto1ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto1.descuentoParaUsuarios();


//Estructura producto 2.
let precioOriginalProducto2 = producto2.precio;
let producto2PrecioConIva = producto2.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto2);
let producto2ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto2.descuentoParaUsuarios();


//Estructura producto 3.
let precioOriginalProducto3 = producto3.precio;
let producto3PrecioConIva = producto3.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto3);
let producto3ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto3.descuentoParaUsuarios();

let cantidadDeProductosPublicados = 0;

//Creación del array que almacena los IDs de los productos.
const numerodID = [producto0.idProducto, producto1.idProducto, producto2.idProducto, producto3.idProducto];

//Creación del array que almacena los precios de los productos.
const preciosDeTodosLosProductos = [producto0PrecioConIva, producto1PrecioConIva, producto2PrecioConIva, producto3PrecioConIva];
preciosDeTodosLosProductos.sort();

//función para ordenar los productos del más barato al más caro.
function ordenar(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
//For: utilizado para recorrer la arrayd en busca de los precios y ordenarlos.
for (let i = 0; i < preciosDeTodosLosProductos.length; i++) {
  console.log(preciosDeTodosLosProductos[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: ¿Llegaste a pasar `ordenar` como función de comparación de `.sort`?

Comment: lo hice y según veo hace la comparación pero siempre queda el objeto "Auto" de primer lugar en la comparación... de hecho veo algo mal en la comparación, no se realiza como debería ser....

Comment: En ese caso, mostrá el resultado esperado. Especificá lo siguiente: ¿estás queriendo ordenar los objetos por id? ¿por nombre del producto? ¿por precio?

Comment: Por precio, debería ser el orden por precio, de menor a mayor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocupas hacer el `sort()` con tu función ordenar... El `for` que tienes ahí solo está imprimiendo tus elementos, no los está ordenando. De hecho nunca se invoca tu función `ordenar`.

```js
class Productos {
  constructor(idProducto, nombreProducto, precio) {
    this.idProducto = idProducto;
    this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
    this.precio = precio;

  }
  sumarIva() {
    this.precio = this.precio * 1.21;
    return this.precio;
    //función creada para agregar el Impuesto al Valor Agregado al precio de los productos.
  }
  descuentoParaUsuarios() {
    this.precio = this.precio - 2000;
    return this.precio;
    //función para realizar descuentos a los usuarios registrados (Más adelante el programa podrá distinguir entre Usuarios registrados y no registrados).
  }
}

//Objetos con los datos de los productos.
const producto0 = new Productos(0, "Ovni", 5000);
const producto1 = new Productos(1, "Tren", 8000);
const producto2 = new Productos(2, "Auto", 30000);
const producto3 = new Productos(3, "Moto", 4000);


//Estructura producto 0.
let precioOriginalProducto0 = producto0.precio;
let producto0PrecioConIva = producto0.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto0);
let producto0ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto0.descuentoParaUsuarios();


//Estructura producto 1.
let precioOriginalProducto1 = producto1.precio;
let producto1PrecioConIva = producto1.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto1);
let producto1ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto1.descuentoParaUsuarios();


//Estructura producto 2.
let precioOriginalProducto2 = producto2.precio;
let producto2PrecioConIva = producto2.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto2);
let producto2ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto2.descuentoParaUsuarios();


//Estructura producto 3.
let precioOriginalProducto3 = producto3.precio;
let producto3PrecioConIva = producto3.sumarIva(precioOriginalProducto3);
let producto3ConDescuentoDeUsuario = producto3.descuentoParaUsuarios();

let cantidadDeProductosPublicados = 0;

//Creación del array que almacena los IDs de los productos.
const numerodID = [producto0.idProducto, producto1.idProducto, producto2.idProducto, producto3.idProducto];

//Creación del array que almacena los precios de los productos.
const preciosDeTodosLosProductos = [producto0PrecioConIva, producto1PrecioConIva, producto2PrecioConIva, producto3PrecioConIva];

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//Tienes que pasar la función a tu sort
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
preciosDeTodosLosProductos.sort(ordenar);


//función para ordenar los productos del más barato al más caro.
function ordenar(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}



//For: utilizado para recorrer la arrayd en busca de los precios y ordenarlos.
for (let i = 0; i < preciosDeTodosLosProductos.length; i++) {
  console.log(preciosDeTodosLosProductos[i] + " ");
}
```